# Erdos distance problem n=12

Tags: erdos, co.combinatorics

The recent paper On the Erdos distinct distance problem in the plane
Authors: Larry Guth, Nets Hawk Katz prodded me to get a non-trivial example.  Here is what I cannot find:  an example of 12 distinct points in the plane with only 5 different distances between points.  The regular 12-polygon has 6 different lengths but I cannot do better. http://oeis.org/A186704 implies that there is one>

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here goes my poor explanation:

Take a regular hexagonal lattice with distance 1 between nearest neighbors, and choose a 15-point equilateral triangle in this lattice (15 is a triangular number). Remove the 3 vertices of the triangle. You'll be left with 12 points and 5 distinct distances.

Edit: Just checked the OEIS reference, and it's available on Google Books. The picture you want is on [page 200](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=cT7TB20y3A8C&pg=PA200).

Answer (score 16):

If I may supplement Logan Maingi's apposite answer with a snapshot of the page to which he refers:

[image: p.200]

(I couldn't resist including the surrounding conjecture.)

Comment: Thanks! I tried to no avail to embed the image, but I'm still rather bad with TeX and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Coming to this very late, but this suggests an interesting secondary conjecture: that a maximal set of points for $k$ distinct distances can always be realized as a subset of the triangular grid. Given the form of the conjecture I presume this has to be wrong, but is a specific $k$ known for which this isn't true?

Answer (score 5):

Thought it might be nice to show the set placed on the hexagonal lattice.

[image: 12 points determining just 5 distinct distances]

Here’s a [Desmos link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eahqvwegpq) if you wish to play around with such point configurations.